# Quotients of Artinian implies Artinian

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose that I and J are ideals of a ring R such that $R/I$ and $R/J$ both Artinian and $I \cap J=(0)$. Prove that then R is Artinian. A similar statement should hold if we replace Artinian with Noetherian. A hint says to use CRT, but I am sure how can it apply apply here, knowing that I, J are not necessarily coprime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the natural ring map $\pi:R\rightarrow (R/I)\times(R/J)$. Its kernel is clearly $I\cap J$, which you've assumed is $0$, so $\pi$ is injective. Thus $\pi$ realizes $R$ as an $R$-submodule of $(R/I)\times(R/J)$. By assumption, $R/I$ and $R/J$ are Artinian rings. Since the ideals of these rings are precisely the $R$-submodules, this means they are Artinian $R$-modules. As finite direct sums and submodules of Artinian $R$-modules are Artinian, it follows that $R$ is an Artinian $R$-module, i.e., $R$ is an Artinian ring. The same argument applies with "Artinian" replaced everywhere by "Noetherian."

Comment: @ Keenan Kidwell:  that looks right!  Now I just need to thoroughly figure it out!  Anyway, +1!